# Dark text on dark background on AlertDialog with Theme.Sherlock.Light

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-dialogfragment

I'm using `Theme.Sherlock.Light` theme for my application and I'm creating a `DialogFragment` with an underlying `AlertDialog`. It works just fine on Android 3.x and 4.x, but on Android 2.x I see dark text on dark background, which is hardly readable. Am I doing something wrong and do I need to force light background by creating a custom style? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/zCiPdYGgFQA):

```
builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true)
```

Also, as I see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/lGuxn7YjTY0), Jake Warton suggests fix it by the same way and he doesn't know any better solution because of AlertDialogs implementation.

Comment: Thanks!  Too bad I didn't find this answer first... I mucked around with creating a theme for my AlertDialog, which is very much not recommended.